# How to read sc.variable programmatically

Tags: configuration

I have added a new sc.variable (just like dataFolder, tempFolder). We see the setting in `showconfig.aspx` but it returns an empty string when getting it with `Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("mySetting")`.

I tried playing around with lowercase/uppercase as `Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("dataFolder")` returns empty but  `Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("DataFolder")` returns the actual value; but didn't work either. Is it not possible to read custom `sc.variable` settings?

UPDATE: We are using sc.variable so we can read this setting from other .config files e.g. `<bla value="$(mySetting)xxx />` but we also happen to need to read it programmatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the variables from sc.variable are defined in two places
For example tempFolder is defined :

```
 <sc.variable name="tempFolder" value="/temp" />
```

and

```
 <setting name="TempFolder" value="$(tempFolder)" />
```

The value of the TempFolder you can get using :

`return Settings.GetSetting("TempFolder", "/temp")` where the second parameter is default value.

So I recommend to declare your variable not like a **sc.variable**, but like normal setting. Or if you declare like a sc.variable declare a setting with a variable parameter.

Update:
   How sitecore replace this variables : 
  On Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigReader it has a method:

```
protected virtual void ReplaceGlobalVariables(System.Xml.XmlNode rootNode)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(rootNode, "rootNode");
    System.Xml.XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = rootNode.SelectNodes(".//sc.variable");
    StringDictionary stringDictionary = new StringDictionary();
    foreach (System.Xml.XmlAttribute xmlAttribute in rootNode.Attributes)
    {
        string name = xmlAttribute.Name;
        string @string = StringUtil.GetString(new string[]
        {
            xmlAttribute.Value
        });
        if (name.Length > 0)
        {
            string key = "$(" + name + ")";
            stringDictionary[key] = @string;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < xmlNodeList.Count; i++)
    {
        string attribute = XmlUtil.GetAttribute("name", xmlNodeList[i]);
        string attribute2 = XmlUtil.GetAttribute("value", xmlNodeList[i]);
        if (attribute.Length > 0)
        {
            string key2 = "$(" + attribute + ")";
            stringDictionary[key2] = attribute2;
        }
    }
    if (stringDictionary.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    this.ReplaceGlobalVariables(rootNode, stringDictionary);
}
```

Comment: You don't say it directly, but you do imply that `sc.variable` must have a `<setting>`. Just to clarify, `sc.variable` does not require a `<setting>` and can, in fact, be used in all config attribute and element values.

Comment: We are using sc.variable so we can read the setting in other config files. This is not possible with <setting>, right?

Answer (score 6):

While the answer given by Sitecore Climber is spot on, I'd like to clarify a bit on the difference between `sc.variable` and a `setting`.

If you look at how `sc.variable` is used throughout the (original) `Sitecore.config`, it is almost always in places that would differ *by environment*. So the config defines a `sc.variable` for `dataFolder` for instance, and then an actual `setting` for it later like `<setting name="dataFolder" value="$(dataFolder" />`.

The *reason* for this is, that you can then isolate all the *environment specific settings* in your solution, and have a simple patch for them. All `sc.variable` declarations would be at the top of the config file, so they could be easily found and replaced.

I don't often see this used any more however. Sitecore later introduced `config patching` and I think, generally, people just use different layers of patch config files to achieve the same result; making the use of `sc.variable` largely obsolete.

Further reading:

- [Manage Sitecore config across environments (DTAP)](http://hermanussen.eu/sitecore/wordpress/2011/05/manage-sitecore-config-across-environments-dtap/)
- [Improve the security of the website folder](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_hardening/configuring/improve_the_security_of_the_website_folder)

Comment: I actually try to use `sc.variable` for as many instance-specific values as I can in my solutions. In my `App_Config/Include` folder I have two child folders `zz.Variables` and `zzz.Patches`. It's great for some things, but patching is where the magic happens. Remember that you don't have to just use them in settings. You can use them anywhere.

Comment: We are using sc.variable so we can read from other config files. Is this possible with <setting>?

Comment: Sure. But as pointed out, you cannot resolve an `sc.variable` directly. You have to put it into a `<setting>` element and then read it using `Configuration.GetSetting` as shown above.

Comment: Cool, that's what we ended up doing. Was trying to figure out if I was missing something. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I used Sitecore PowerShell Extensions to read a specific variable value.

```powershell
$config = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetConfiguration()
$speSourceFolder = $config.sitecore."sc.variable" | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "speSourceFolder" } | 
    Select-Object -First 1 -Expand value
```

[image]